# Google Apps Script adds a tiny, undesired fraction when I increment in a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Apps Scripts Editor in Google Sheets to run some calculations, but I keep running into an error in my for loops.

Below is a truncated version of my function that has all of the calculations removed and just shows the loops with some counting variables. I've reduced all of the loops, except the 2nd, to only loop through one value. The expected number of iterations should be 27, but I was only getting 26 so I decided to capture each iteration in an array and log that array.

```
function myFunction() {

  var timestamp = new Date();
  Logger.log(timestamp);

  // Define parameter ranges and increments.
  var WTmin = 0.3055,  WTmax = /*0.3215*/0.3055,  WTinc = 0.0010,
      FTmin = 0.1370,  FTmax = 0.1630,  FTinc = 0.0010,
      LLmin = 0.0700,  LLmax = /*0.1200*/0.0700,  LLinc = 0.0010,
      HHmin = 0.2050,  HHmax = /*0.2450*/0.2050,  HHinc = 0.0010,
      CBDmin = 0.0650, CBDmax = /*0.1150*/ 0.0650, CBDinc = 0.0010,
      count = 0;
  var check = [];

  // Loop through all of the combinations
  for (var WT = WTmin; WT <= WTmax; WT += WTinc) {
    for (var FT = FTmin; FT <= FTmax; FT += FTinc) {
      for (var LL = LLmin; LL <= LLmax; LL += LLinc) {
        for (var HH = HHmin; HH <= HHmax; HH += HHinc) {
          for (var CBD = CBDmin; CBD <= CBDmax; CBD += CBDinc) {
            count++;
            check.push(FT);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The log is below:

```
[15-09-02 19:20:58:047 PDT] count: 26
[15-09-02 19:28:58:506 PDT] check: [0.137,0.138,0.139,0.14,0.14100000000000001,0.14200000000000002,0.14300000000000002,0.14400000000000002,0.14500000000000002,0.14600000000000002,0.14700000000000002,0.14800000000000002,0.14900000000000002,0.15000000000000002,0.15100000000000002,0.15200000000000002,0.15300000000000002,0.15400000000000003,0.15500000000000003,0.15600000000000003,0.15700000000000003,0.15800000000000003,0.15900000000000003,0.16000000000000003,0.16100000000000003,0.16200000000000003]
```

For some reason, when the loop is incremented, a tiny fraction is being added on. Thus, my loop only goes through 26 iterations because the additional fraction is triggering the end of my loop. Can someone please explain why this is happens and/or suggest a fix?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I was planning on trying something like that tomorrow actually. I'm pretty new with JavaScript and programming in general. I was thinking of using Math.round() or toFixed(). What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

this is not specific to apps script. its expected in any language that uses floating point (like javascript).

in your case you need to round the values to the wanted decimal digits you want.

Comment: In which portion of the script would you recommend rounding? Do I need to round the value every time it is incremented? Also, do you recommend using Math.round() or some other method? Thanks!

Comment: For some reason I thought you could specify to what decimal place to round to with Math.round(). That doesn't appear to be the case after reading some documentation. Maybe toFixed() it is then.

Comment: you can use either. just multiply by say 10000, round, then divide by 10000. you can also change the math to do the dividing on a single number each time thus prevent error accumulation due to roundings. for example calculate the divisor according to the loop.

Comment: but solving that here is really beyond the scope of this question.